# Access tree object in netbeans outline

Tags: java, swing, outline

I'm using `Outline` from netbeans to display some structured data.

How can I map selected row to an object in tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might look at the example in [*Announcing the new Swing Tree Table today*](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component). It looks like the author is [*Creating a Data Model*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data), so [*Responding to Node Selection*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#select) should be helpful. I find the class `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline` in NetBeans 6.8:

> `NetBeans/platform11/modules/org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar`

Addenda:

Note that `Outline` descends from `JTable`, so [*How to Use Tables: User Selections*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) may be helpful. Based on the example cited above, here's a listener that shows the apparent change in row number as nodes expand and collapse and the selection remains constant:

```
outline.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int row = outline.getSelectedRow();
        File f = (File) outline.getValueAt(row, 0);
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            System.out.println(row + ": " + f);
        }
    }
});
```

Although [provisional](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/index.html), you might look at `OutlineModel` and `DefaultOutlineModel`. The former implements both `TreeModel` and `TableModel` and offers `TreePathSupport`; the latter mentions the "impedance mismatch between TableModelEvent and TreeModelEvent."

Like `JTable`, the selected row index in the view may not match the corresponding row in the model, perhaps due to sorting, etc. The `getValueAt()` method seems a convenient way to call `convertRowIndexToModel()`. This is common in Swing's separable model architecture, which "collapses the view and controller parts of each component into a single UI (user-interface) object." See [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).

Comment: Outline provides only getSelectedRow() method. But index of the row depends on expanded/collapsed state of nodes above.

I see no way to map index of selected row to an object in TreeModel.

Comment: See above. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it seems like you can traverse your `RowModel` or `TreeModel` as required.

Comment: It is some kind of ugly solution, to track view to get information for model, that I tried to avoid. But it seems to be the only way at the moment. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Interesting. I think this an artifact of Swing's architecture; see above.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110/file-browser-gui/6182305#6182305).