# How to create a drop-down list in java swing with multiple item selection?

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, multipleselection

I'm aware of `JList` and `JComboBox`. I need the combo box drop down functionality with multiple selection functionality that `JList` provides.

This is because the contents of the list are too huge to be displayed using a simple list. I also need to select multiple items, otherwise I would have been content with `JComboBox`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using multi-select, it's better to use a list than a combo box.  As GUI idioms go, people expect a combo box to be single select, whereas lists can be either.

> the contents of the list are too huge to be displayed using a simple list

Place the `JList` in a `JScrollPane`.  You can call [setVisibleRowCount(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) on the `JList` to specify how many rows at a time should be shown.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a custom cell renderer for the combobox and add checkboxes to that components, so you can check and uncheck them. You have to make something like this:

```
public class MyComboBoxRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    private String[] items;
    private boolean[] selected;

    public MyComboBoxRenderer(String[] items){
         this.items = items;
         this.selected = new boolean[items.lenght];
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int index) {
         // Create here a JLabel with the text
         // Create here a JCheckBox
         // Add them to a layoutmanager
         return this;
    }

    public void setSelected(int i, boolean flag)
    {
         this.selected[i] = flag;
    }

}
```

Comment: This class must extends some subtypes of `Component` in order to make the return type of `getListCellRendererComponent()` match, if you want to `return this;`. If you want to return the label you created, it's ok the original(so I don't really get it). And where does this `setSelected()` come from? Best to post all code.

Answer (score 2):

If your data has a hierarchical character, consider NetBeans' `Outline` component, discussed in [*Announcing the new Swing Tree Table*](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component) and in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841582). Here's the [*Current Development Version*](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/index.html) of the API.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the described functionality, I finally decided to "abuse" the `JMenuBar` and add to it several `JCheckBoxMenuItems`. The GUI then perfectly fits the purpose (at least for me), it is just the handling of the ItemEvent that risks to become a bit annoying.

(finally there, I defined some bit logic over the items, and then may restrict myself to handling only one type of event)