# JcomboBox multiple selection

Tags: swing, jcombobox, multi-select

I have a jcombobox in my application.
and i want it to support multiple selection (like it do in a jlist).
is there any code example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's not possible, unless you use a JList, like you said.

The [JComboBox API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) reports:

> The user can select a value from the drop-down list, which appears at
>   the user's request.

And a JComboBox [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html):

> Lists are not terribly attractive, but they're more appropriate than
>   combo boxes when the number of items is large (say, over 20) or when
>   selecting multiple items might be valid.

**Update:**

I reviewed this answer, because actually it's "possible" to do that using a ListCellRenderer, adding a checkbox to each item. Please consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860376/702048) to implement this "solution".

However, I don't think it's a good idea for the following reasons:

1. there's a control like a JList that allows multiple selection;
2. a JComboBox control is designed just for single item selection;
3. it doesn't make sense to me to still use a JComboBox control and allow a multiple selection.

Comment: No, it's possible but have to use Renderer

Comment: @PeerNet Yes, but it's still not a good idea for me. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite impossible but there's a lot of work to do to get the job done. You'll need to create your own classes to extend/implement all of these:

- ListCellRenderer   (so you can mark the selected items when the popup is showing and indicate (at least) that there are multiple selections when it is not).
- JComboBox          (obviously)
- BasicComboBoxUI    (this is actually where most of the work is)
- BasicListUI        (at least I had to)
- ComboBoxModel

And you'll need to develop your own class that implements ItemListener, MouseListener, PopupMenuListener, MouseMotionListener, PropertyChangeListener, KeyListener, ListSelectionListener.
Hint: you'll need to override a lot of createXXXListener() methods in the UI classes in order to bypass the many places where multiple selections are discarded.
[And it still doesn't allow for an **editable** multi-selection combo.]