# Colouring JTree's TreeNodes

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a `JTree` which I give objects that implement the `TreeNode` interface, and a custom `TreeModel` to display them (not using `DefaultMutableTreeNode`). I would like to change the text colour of some nodes. I can't find anything in the docs, except `javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeCellRenderer.setTextNonSelectionColor(Color newColor)`, but it will change everything indiscriminately, and I only need it for some nodes (specifically, broken links, i.e. nodes whose corresponding files can't be found on the disk, should be greyed out, the rest should be default). Can it be done, and how?

Comment: See also `TreeIconDemo2` in _How to Use Trees_  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

Comment: Doh! Thank you! "Because `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` is a subclass of `JLabel`, you can use any `JLabel` method — such as `setIcon` — to customize the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`." Big thanks to both you and @Justin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close to your answer.  What you need to do is Sub Class the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` and override a few of the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`'s methods.  Then make sure you tell the tree to use your custom cell renderer.

What you will need to do is have some state variables that indicate whether or not a link is broken, and set the color of the node based on that.

Comment: Obviously, state variables were not a problem :), but purely `JTree`'s interface... Anyway, did you mean ` getTreeCellRendererComponent`? Is it as simple as just returning a JLabel from that function? Will try when I get a bit of free time, in couple of hours. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at [`org.netbeans.swing.outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/package-summary.html), mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841582). Ordinary extensions of [`TableCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and the [`RenderDataProvider`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/RenderDataProvider.html) interface make it especially easy to customize the appearance of rows in the tree.