# File explorer java

Tags: java, windows-explorer, directory-listing

I'd like to have some kind of file browser like Windows Explorer inside a Java Application.

I just want something that's able to list file inside a folder recursively.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

I already tried to use JFileChooser but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This snippet allows you to list all files recursivly. You could use the data to populate a JTree see this [tutorial](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html)

```
public class Filewalker { 

    public void walk( String path ) { 

        File root = new File( path ); 
        File[] list = root.listFiles(); 

        for ( File f : list ) { 
            if ( f.isDirectory() ) { 
                walk( f.getAbsolutePath() ); 
                System.err.println( "Dir:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() ); 
            } 
            else { 
                System.err.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() ); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Filewalker fw = new Filewalker(); 
        fw.walk("c:\\" ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: +1 for recursion. You might also like the example in org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline, mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I'm not going to do -1 but: there is a file instance, and then you check if it is a folder. If so, you pass the path and create a new instance, while you can use just the existing one.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this would help you (this is from a quick googling, I don't do GUIs but felt obliged to help):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/FileTreewithPopupMenu.htm

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, [`java.awt.FileDialog`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) offers more native look that may suffice. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914733) that also references a more versatile component, [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html).