# Is there a way to improve JFileChooser look and feel under Ubuntu?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, look-and-feel, jfilechooser

I've been making a program that uses a JFileChooser. I've set the application up with

> UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()

Which works just fine for pretty much everything under Ubuntu. The only problem I've run into so far is that the JFileChooser comes out looking pretty awful:
[image: JFileChooser with SystemLookAndFeel]

Is there a way to make this look like the default file chooser in Ubuntu? ie.
[image: Desired file chooser dialog]

I've tried using

> UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()

Which makes the JFileChooser dialog look *better*, but still not native looking, and it ruins the rest off the application's feel too.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to below link for the solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597831/improving-jfilechooser-under-ubuntu-12-04-gtk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the stock JDK used gtk1, but ubuntu uses gtk2 currently. I forget where but i've come across gtk2 for java somewhere. Google? Probably not what you were hoping for, sorry.

Comment: Searching this did help, I ran into this: https://code.google.com/p/gtkjfilechooser/ . Not sure how I can make this perform cross-platform, but I'll look more into it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could probably do what jzd was suggesting you do with nimbus and add this as a seperate lib in your project and only use the look on systems that want a gtk native look.

Answer (score 1):

You might see if [`FileDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) is any more appealing; here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914733).

[image: FileDialog]

Comment: This is not that appealing to me, but thanks for the tip anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The Nimbus look and feel has a decent file chooser.  Although this will affect your entire application, you might like the look.

Also you can build your own file chooser if needed.

Comment: Nimbus was only added in Java 6 update 10, I think. I'm trying to stay away from forcing specific Java versions (might be able to do a fall-back somehow?), but I'll definitely look into this, thanks.

Comment: Before it was included in the JRE it was a separate library that you would include in your project.  That would work for older versions of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SWT instead of swing.

[Does Swing support Windows 7-style file choosers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703825/does-swing-support-windows-7-style-file-choosers)

The following code is from above link

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class SWTFileOpenSnippet {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        // Don't show the shell.
        //shell.open ();  
        FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog (shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.MULTI);
        String [] filterNames = new String [] {"All Files (*)"};
        String [] filterExtensions = new String [] {"*"};
        String filterPath = "c:\\";
        dialog.setFilterNames (filterNames);
        dialog.setFilterExtensions (filterExtensions);
        dialog.setFilterPath (filterPath);
        dialog.open();
        System.out.println ("Selected files: ");
        String[] selectedFileNames = dialog.getFileNames();
        for(String fileName : selectedFileNames) {
            System.out.println("  " + fileName);
        }
        shell.close();
        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```