# jfilechooser better look?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

When I'm using `JFileChooser` application in my program on Windows 7 it display such window:

[image: Metal JFileChooser]

But when I run the [JWS File Chooser Demo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/JWSFileChooserDemo.jnlp) it displays much better window:

[image: JWS File Chooser Demo]

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703825/does-swing-support-windows-7-style-file-choosers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the demo doesn't use JFileChooser; it uses `javax.jnlp.FileOpenService`, which uses the native OS's file dialog. The source code for that demo is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/JWSFileChooserDemoProject/src/components/JWSFileChooserDemo.java), check it out.

Answer (score 5):

The major difference could be solved by using the native look and feel.  See the `main()` of [FileBro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182110) for how to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The Oracle Java Web Start app, is actually using the JNLP API instead of Swing's `JFileChooser`.

Here is a link: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/jnlpAPI.html

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
          try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```