# JFileChooser is not opening default Win 7 File Explorer

Tags: java, swing, swt, jfilechooser

I am using `JFileChooser` to open the File Explorer in WIN 7 and realized that its opening the old UI , but same SWT `FileDialog` is opening the WIN 7 File Explorer only.

Is there any specific reason.

`JFileChooser`:
[image]

SWT `FileDialog`:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- AFAIK this not possible for AWT / Swing, Java 6 / 7 missed that, some implementetion as for WinXP (maybe for Vista too, never used this "middle_Win" version)
- [question about the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703825/does-swing-support-windows-7-style-file-choosers), incl. code for test
- there were some promisses about update to later Java7 (not in present time)

Comment: Nice find. Marked this question as duplicate of your link.