# JFileChooser showing the directory at the top just like in Windows

Tags: java, swing, windows-7, jfilechooser

Is there a way to make the JFileChooser show the directory string at the top of the dialog just like in Windows? I need it because in that way, the users can paste the value they want instead of traversing the hierarchy every time.

**PS:** I'd like to avoid custom FileChoosers if possible.

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

Comment: [I think that still not possible for Win7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471587/jfilechooser-is-not-opening-default-win-7-file-explorer), sorry too lazy test this issue in Java8, were decribed a few times could/will be fixed,(-: maybe in the summer :-)

Comment: Users can paste a directory into the "File Name" field and press enter to navigate to that directory.

Comment: @VGR That's a possible solution too!

Comment: 1- Your using metal look and feel, it's highly unlikely to be the default behaviour. 2- you'd need to implement your own look and feel

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't have experience with Look & Feel, but I do use them, is it possible to have the ability to paste the value of the directory in the top box as in the Windows one?

Comment: @AdelBoutros With the current implementations, no, but I'm sure it would be possible to customise them to do so.  Are you will to write a custom look and feel implementation for each look and feel you want to support?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I never said I was just aiming for Windows... Anyway, I believe the only solution is extending the file chooser to customize it.

Comment: @AdelBoutros I don't think extending `JFileChooser` is the best choice as it each Look & Feel changes, well, what it looks like.  You will need to provide a Look and Feel implementation - IHMO

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to use the `FileChooser` from `JavaFX`. It has all the features needed to emulate the Windows file dialog.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html