# An SWT FileDialog Selected Directories Only in Swing

Tags: java, swing, swt

I have a swing app that I would like to use Windows7/Vista style FileDialogs and have found a reasonable solution using SWT in conjunction with swing:
[Does Swing support Windows 7-style file choosers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703825/does-swing-support-windows-7-style-file-choosers)

However, now I'm trying to get this same dialog to accept only directories (the "Select Folder" button instead of the "Open" button).

I *do not* want to use the typical DirectoryDialog:

[image]

I want to use the Dialog with favorites on the left, address bar on the top, and the ability to select folders:

[image]

Anyone know how to accomplish this?
Replies are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simple answer is: You can't. That's what the `DirectoryDialog` is for. There currently is no way to get the "Windows 7 style" dialog for choosing directories with SWT, sorry.

Comment: What about with any other framework in Java? Is it just that Java can't use that type of dialog that only selects folders? Seems strange.

Comment: No idea, I don't use other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Baz already said it: It is not possible to get this dialog using SWT.
To answer your question about other frameworks:
I believe there are plenty, for example you could use [Jide](http://www.jidesoft.com/). You do not get the dialog you want, but at least you get an enhanced version (FolderChooser) with few advantages:

- Convenience-Buttons (Desktop, My Documents, ...)
- Delete/Create new directory
- Address bar

And the best of all this: You get it for free, cause it's in the "Common Layer".
You can try the FolderChooser by launching the Demo-WebStart-Project.

Comment: I have kind of a solution for that:

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of a hack:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Demo{

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);  
        FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.MULTI);
        dialog.setFilterPath("c:\\");

        //The extension doen't excist!
        dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] {"xyz"});
        //You can also use " ";

        dialog.open();
        shell.close();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

I tryed it out and I think, it works well!