# improving JFileChooser under Ubuntu 12.04 (GTK)

Tags: java, swing, ubuntu, jfilechooser, filedialog

I have a problem with the `JFileChooser` under Ubuntu 12.04. I use this code to set the look and feel:
`javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(javax.swing.UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

And it looks like this. It's very uncomfortable to use and it looks very ugly:

[image]
<sub>(source: [picfront.org](http://www9.picfront.org/token/9sRH/2012/05/15/2062476.jpg))</sub>

I would like it to look like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [picfront.org](http://www4.picfront.org/token/1lpa/2012/05/15/2062477.jpg))</sub>

Using the hint from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983575/is-there-a-way-to-improve-jfilechooser-look-and-feel-under-ubuntu), I tried to use `FileDialog` instead of the `FileChooser`. But `FileDialog` throws an exception when i start it in `LOAD` mode and click on the "open" button.
The way i create the Dialog:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Test", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setVisible(true);
```

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.X11.GtkFileDialogPeer.setFileInternal(GtkFileDialogPeer.java:79)
at sun.awt.X11.GtkFileDialogPeer.run(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11.GtkFileDialogPeer.showNativeDialog(GtkFileDialogPeer.java:172)
at sun.awt.X11.GtkFileDialogPeer.access$000(GtkFileDialogPeer.java:39)
at sun.awt.X11.GtkFileDialogPeer$1.run(GtkFileDialogPeer.java:114)
```

I am using Oracle JDK7 under Ubuntu Linux 12.04 with Gnome 3 (if this helps).

Does anybody got an idea how either i could improve the look of the `JFileChooser` or get the `FileDialog` working?

Comment: no idea why you got an exeption, I haven't any issue on Win OS, for potential answerers you have to edit your question with a [SSCCE](http://example.com), there are a few answerers using *nix clones,

Comment: There is an image button to embed a picture.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in a Java GUI project I was working on. I set it to use "zenity" terminal program to call the native file-chooser on Linux/unix systems. Note that this solution does not require importing any extra Java libraries (You must have Zenity installed on Linux though), and also works fine on Windows:

```
private File fileSelection(boolean savemode) {
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
        File input = null;
        String zenity = "zenity --file-selection --title=Open";
        String filestring;
        if ((os.indexOf("nix")!=-1 || os.indexOf("nux")!=-1)) {
            //Use native Linux file selection.
            try {
                if (savemode) {
                    zenity ="zenity --file-selection --title=Save --save";
                }
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(zenity);  
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  
                String line;
                /*while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
                  sb.append(line).append("\n");  
                } */
                sb.append(br.readLine());
                filestring = sb.toString();  
                if (filestring.equals("null")) {
                    return null;
                }
                System.out.println(filestring);
                input = new File(filestring);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal;
            if (savemode) {
                returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);
            } else {
                returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);  
            }
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                input = fc.getSelectedFile();
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness' sake, here's the [java-forum.org thread](http://www.java-forum.org/awt-swing-swt/136248-jfilechooser-gtk-ubuntu-haesslich.html) where you posted about the same question in German.

User eRaaaa posted a [fix to this bug](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/awt-dev/2012-January/002154.html), which subsequently was turned into a [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7130662) at bugs.sun.com that was reviewed positively.

Answer (score 0):

A NullPointerException usually means you are pointing to something that is not there. I suppose the reference you try to point to is lost, during runtime.