# Reading/Opening a text file in Java

Tags: java, file, text

I know that there are probably hundreds of posts dealing with this exact question, but for the life of me, I cannot figure anything out. I have this "Open" case in this program I have committed myself to finishing, as a beginning Java exercise. I've gotten the Save function to work, but looking at that gets me no closer to trying my problem. Here is my code.

```
if(arg.equals(Editor.fileLabels[0])){
    if(Editor.VERBOSE)
    System.err.println(Editor.fileLabels[0] + 
               " has been selected");
    filedialog = new FileDialog(editor, "Open File Dialog", FileDialog.LOAD); 
    filedialog.setVisible(true);
    if(Editor.VERBOSE){ 
    System.err.println("Exited filedialog.setVisible(true);");
    System.err.println("Open file = " + filedialog.getFile());
    System.err.println("Open directory = " + filedialog.getDirectory()); 
    }

}
```

I have tried solutions before writing this question; however, all of the examples I've seen are separate methods of their own. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: yea, I have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: In this day & age, don't use AWT components.  The Swing file chooser is [JFileChooser](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

Comment: @Andrew: One advantage of [`java.awt.FileDialog`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) is that it typically evokes the platform's native file dialog; see also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914627/file-explorer-using-java-how-to-go-about-it/2914733#2914733).

Comment: @trashgod:  *"..typically evokes the platform's native file dialog.."* True, but **apparently** not in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703825/does-swing-support-windows-7-style-file-choosers/5704000#5704000).

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, I overlooked the XP style dialog under 7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Whatever UI framework you are using, you will only have results of file dialog available after it was closed by user. In your case, you have shown dialog and immediately expect directory and file be available. It's not going to happen as dialog is probably still open.

Also it's all based on my guesses since you didn't really tell what is wrong and what you expect.

Comment: @Andrew Sure. My Swing and AWT days are long gone. But I am pretty sure that FileDialog from awt or JFileChooser would not wait on `setVisible` and that was my point. So I removed word Swing to not offend people who are experts in the field.

Comment: *"..I removed word Swing.."* +1

Answer (score 1):

public class FileReadWrite {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new  FileInputStream("Path for the file/filename.txt");

        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        File file = new File("Path for the file/filename.txt");
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));


        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            // Print the content on the console
            System.out.println (strLine);
            String[] words = strLine.split("\\s+");
            String revrseStrline="";
            for(int i=words.length-1;i>=0; i-- )
            {
                revrseStrline+=words[i]+" ";
            }

            writer.write(revrseStrline);
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

          }

         // Close the input stream
        in.close();
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { // Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}