# How to use FileDialog?

Tags: java, awt

I created an interface and I'd like to add a function that allows user to open a file. I'm using AWT. I don't understand how to use FileDialog. Can you please give me an example or a good link that explain this?

Comment: See also [`FileDialogTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914627/file-explorer-using-java-how-to-go-about-it/2914733#2914733).

Answer (score 50):

A complete code example, with file filtering:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(yourJFrame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setDirectory("C:\\");
fd.setFile("*.xml");
fd.setVisible(true);
String filename = fd.getFile();
if (filename == null)
  System.out.println("You cancelled the choice");
else
  System.out.println("You chose " + filename);
```

Comment: this helped alot, its much faster than a `JFileChooser`, shame it doesn't handle exceptions well, that `null` bit was tripping me up.

Answer (score 13):

To add to the answer by @TheBronx - for me, `fd.setFile("*.txt");` is not working on OS X.  This works:

```
fd.setFilenameFilter(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

Or as a fancy Java 8 lambda:

```
fd.setFilenameFilter((dir, name) -> name.endsWith(".txt"));
```

Comment: Great solution but it won't work on Windows. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html#setFilenameFilter%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29

Comment: @KenoClayton True. I think the cross-platform solution is to use both `setFile` and `setFilenameFilter`.

Comment: @NealEhardt Yes that's what I had to resort to. I'd simply check if it was windows and use the relevant function.

Comment: Found a "bug": setFilenameFilter() must be called before setVisible() to work! Tested on MAC "High Sierra".

Answer (score 3):

There's a few code samples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/FileDialog.htm) that demonstrate how to use it for various different tasks.

That said, you might want to take a step back and check whether awt is the best task for the job here. There are valid reasons for using it over something like swing / swt of course, but if you're just starting out then Swing, IMO would be a better choice (there's more components, more tutorials and it's a more widely requested library to work with these days.)

Comment: All three of the code samples that that link leads to are the exact same... (just saying, if they look similar, you're not crazy...)