# Are there O.S specific APIs for calling file chooser dialog box in Windows, Linux and Mac?

Tags: java, electron, native, jfilechooser, filechooser

I am looking for native file choosers dialog boxes for Windows, Linux, and Mac. I was using Java Swing file chooser and I am currently looking for Non-Java alternatives for the same.

What should be the right way to deal with this situation? There are alternatives such as Electron and even some C++ tools which provide the native file chooser. Is that my best bet?

One of my primary concerns is to invoke a native file chooser.

Comment: If you're using Java, why do you care about a native alternative?  That defeats the purpose of java.  I think the best Java would have is SWT.

Comment: Hi,
I am making my application move away from Java. The file-chooser for my application is already implemented using Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the default File Chooser for the operating system? java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745198/how-to-use-the-default-file-chooser-for-the-operating-system-java)

Comment: Sorry guys, I am looking for a non-Java file chooser. I have already mentioned that in my description!