# How to filter files without extensions using file dialog in Java

Tags: java, rcp, file-browser

In my application I need to select files with out file extension using file dialog. Is there a way to achieve this? Please help me to find a solution for this.
My current code with out any filter is given below:

```
@Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {

                FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.NONE);
                String filePath = dialog.open();
                if (filePath != null && !filePath.equals("")) {
                    //Do my Operations

                }

            }
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211107/how-to-use-filedialog)

Comment: when the dialog is shown up to select a file, you need to display only the file  which are without any extensions (means flat files) ? Am i rite?

Comment: Yes.I need to display files without any extensions with *.txt files

Comment: Hi GGrec,Thanks for the replay.I read the link shared by you.It only says how to filter files with extensions. I want to filter files without extensions.

Comment: @EJoe it cannot be done. You can not filter and show only the files without extension. You can filter and show only files with extension. See http://superuser.com/questions/691083/view-only-files-without-extension-in-file-choose-windows-7/691094?noredirect=1#691094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileNameExtensionFilter` class won't allow you to filter with empty extensions. So, create your own `FileFilter`.

```
FileFilter filterWithoutExtension = new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            // This will display only the files without "."
            return !f.getName().contains(".");
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Files Without Extension";
        }
};
```

Then set this one as your `FileFilter`.

```
myFileChooser.setFileFilter(filterWithoutExtension);
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using FileDialog.Is it possible to create my own FileFilter and use it with fileDialog?.