# How can I open a file from the explorer and copy to a directory?

Tags: java, file, directory, copy, explorer

I have a little problem,
I need to do a program that open the file explorer and copy the selected file in a specified directory.
I've only found how to open the explorer :

```
 File file = new File ("c:\\<directory>");
 Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
 desktop.open(file);
```

but I need to get the selected file and copy in a default directory, and I really don't know how to do it.
 Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a SWT Java Application. Then you can use `FileDialog` to show a file chooser where the user selects a file. Without a GUI it wouldn't be easy to show a file choosing dialog to the user.
This code snippet uses `FileUtils` from Apache Commons IO:

```
FileDialog dlg = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a file to copy", FileDialog.OPEN);
dlg.setVisible(true); // blocks until user completes the action
String fileToCopyString = dlg.getFile();

if (fileToCopyString != null) {
  File fileToCopy = new File(fileToCopyString);

  if (fileToCopy.isFile()) {
    FileUtils.copyFile(fileToCopy, new File(tmpDir, fileToCopy.getName());
  }
}
```

**References:**

- [FileDialog Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html)
- [FileUtils Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
- [How to use FileDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211107/how-to-use-filedialog)

Answer (score 0):

Try read the file and write it to another directory. You can use `FileReader()` and `FileWriter()` methods.