# Swing - JFileChooser open dialog does not show images for various options

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I'm using JFileChooser API for opening a file. When open dialogbox appears, it does not show images for various option like, **Up one lever**, **Create new Folder**, **List**, **Details**. Some of the option is also not visible untill mouse hover. Here is the image :
[image]

My code looks something like this:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
FileFilter xlsExcelType = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel spreadsheet (.xls)", "xls");
FileFilter xlsxExcelType = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx)", "xlsx");
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(xlsExcelType);
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(xlsxExcelType);

fileChooser.setFileFilter(xlsxExcelType);

int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
    File file= fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
}
```

Kndly pass your idea to make those option visible with image.
Thanks

Comment: What Java version are you seeing that in?  Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?  Very nice (or at least very instructive) screen-shot BTW.

Comment: @AndrewThompson My java version is jdk1.6.0_02. The file chooser is the part of my project I'm currently working in. It runs pretty fine when I use this code in SSCCE, but UI looks different.

Comment: I remember having this problem years ago. It was either an old JRE or an old JDK, because it is fixed now. What version of Java are you running on? I think upgrading to the latest version of the JRE or JDK will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Look and see if [`java.awt.FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html) has the option(s) you want. If not, you might try ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914627/261156) or [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446).