# expand collapse JeditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am creating a XMl editor. I want the JeditorPane to have expand collapse feature accoring to nodes.. If anybody is having any idea how to do it please tell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an example of folding code.
http://java-sl.com/collapse_area.html
and one more exmple of XMLEditorKit (with expanding/collapsing nodes)
http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html

Regards,
Stas

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [`org.netbeans.swing.outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/package-summary.html), as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841582). Because [`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html) extends `JTable`, custom [rendering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) is relatively easy. I'd put an [`Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html) on the left and a `JEditorPane` on the right of a `JSplitPane`; use a `ListSelectionListener` to update the `JEditorPane` accordingly.