# Multi Dimensional array to JTree in java

Tags: java, jtree, jtreetable

i want to assign a multidimensional array to jtree. how can i do this?

here is sample of an array:

ROOT:{ FolderA : {FileA,FileB} , FolderB: {FileA,FileB} } ....

Also i want to determine files and assign icon to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get model from your jtree and then operate on it. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SimpleSwingtreeTreescanbevastlymorecomplex.htm) you have working example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice [article](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component) showing how to use `org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline` for this. There's more in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841582). Ordinary extensions of [`TableCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) or the [`RenderDataProvider`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/RenderDataProvider.html) interface make it especially easy to customize the appearance of rows in the tree.