# How to implement expand/collapse nature to JTables in Java swing application

Tags: java, swing, jtable, expand

In my application I am displaying a list of tables with huge data. All of the tables may not fit in the window, we need to scroll to see the bottom tables. Here I need expand/collapse nature to the tables. User may select which tables he would like to see among all of the tables. This is my sample screen shot of the application.

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DesignGridTest(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel masterpanel = new JPanel();
        DesignGridLayout masterlayout = new DesignGridLayout(masterpanel);

        JCheckBox chk1 = new JCheckBox("Check Box1");
        masterlayout.row().left().add(chk1);    

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JTable table1 = new JTable();
        table1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        panel1.add(table1);
        final IRow row1 = masterlayout.row().grid().add(panel1);
        chk1.setSelected(true);
        chk1.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
        {
            @Override public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                    row1.show();
                else
                    row1.hide();
                frame.pack();
            }
        });     
        frame.add(masterpanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){new DesignGridTest();}
```

Add panels(panel1,panel2..) to 'masterlayout' to get your desired look

Answer (score 3):

1. You can try [JXTreeTable](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-37-2006-09-10/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html) or [TreeTable](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/)
2. or you can switch jtable's visibility to make a expand/collapse effect. First when it is visible and use selects collapse use `setVisible(false);` and do reverse in expand. [Not sure this will work or not.]

Comment: For point 2, it may work, depending on the LayoutManager used. Some LayoutManager are able to handle dynamic visibility of components and others can't.

Comment: @jfpoilpret: yes. that's why I have written not sure about that point as we don't know which layout manager OP is using.

Answer (score 2):

[`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html) is an appealing alternative, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841183/access-tree-object-in-netbeans-outline/2841582#2841582) and [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component).

Answer (score 2):

The expand/collapse effect based on visibility, as proposed as 2nd option by Harry, can be easy to achieve if you use [DesignGridLayout](http://java.net/projects/designgridlayout/pages/Home):

```
DesignGridLayout layout = new DesignGridLayout(panel);
...
JCheckBox expand1 = newCheckBox("First");
layout.row().left().add(expand1);
final IRow row = layout.row().grid().add(table1);
expand.setSelected(true);
expand.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
{
    @Override public void itemStateChanged(ItemIvent event)
    {
        if (event.getStateChanged() == ItemIvent.SELECTED)
            row.show();
        else
            row.hide();
    }
};
```

Repeat the code above (after "`...`") for every table in your `panel`.

With the code above, each label is replace with a checkbox that, when unselected, hides the table underneath.

You can take a look at DesignGridLayout example application (available as WebStart on the home page) under the "**Dynamic Layouts**" section.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative is to use SwingX' JXTaskPane

```
  JXTaskPaneContainer container = new JXTaskPaneContainer();
  forEach table:
     JXTaskPane pane = new JXTaskPane(tableTitle);
     pane.add(table);
     container.add(pane);
  somePanel.add(new JScrollPane(container);
```

Edited (forgot the taskPane in the snippet, never post before-coffee ;-)

Comment: Where can i find this jar file and how to use it with Netbeans IDE